# Given that $\sum\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$, how can I find $\sum\frac{1}{n^6}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis

Given that $\sum\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$, how can I find $\sum\frac{1}{n^6}$? I know that you can prove the first equality using Fourier analysis. For the second one, do I try to use a different function?

Comment: Do you know about the $\zeta$ function? That is how I was taught to find such sums, by writing them $\zeta(2k)$ where $k=3$ for your case.

Comment: @TonyS.F. Not really. The hint is to integrate $|x|$ but I don't see how that leads to $\frac{1}{n^6}$ though, the power is just too high. I am told that the result would be a rational number times $\pi^6$.

Comment: Yes it will be a rational number times $\pi^6$ but the only reason I know that is because $\zeta(2k)\sim \pi^{2k}$. What kind of fourier series do you get for $|x|$? Maybe try integrating that series term by term?

Comment: you can use the Fourier series again : integrate two times $f(x) = x - \lfloor x \rfloor - 1/2$ (and each time choose the integration constant such that the result is zero-mean)

Comment: @TonyS.F. : $x - \lfloor x \rfloor = 1/2 - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2 \pi n x)}{\pi n}$, this is how you prove the functional equation for $\zeta(s) = s \int_0^\infty (x - \lfloor x \rfloor) x^{-s-1} dx$,  hence $(1-2^{s}) \zeta(s) = \int_0^\infty  \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{\sin(2 \pi n x)}{\pi n} x^{-s-1} dx $ $= \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{-1+s}  \int_0^\infty \sin(2 \pi x) x^{-s-1} dx $ $= \zeta(1-s)(1-2^{s})\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \sin(2 \pi x) x^{-s-1} dx$

Comment: My thought would be to start with the infinite series of 1/(1-x) and manipulate until I had this. Not sure it will work, but it may.